# Firebase encrypted Chat app Runtime error. DatasnapShot to string?

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to take in a string(message) and encrypt it then send it to the firebase database. Then when the app loads the data should be displayed to the user un-encrypted. So the encrypted string lies on the server/database.

Im getting nul pointer exception because it seems when you use snapshot it calls the default message constructor which does not contain the text which i called for.Essentially datasnapshot calls the default constructor which does not let me call the attributes of the object in the actual constructor. Is there anyway around this ?

Once the app request the Method that will request the messages from the database.The App crashes. I try to de-crypt the messages from a String of bytes  before i display them... The messages however will no display and the app crashes

Here's a link to a screenshot

http://ibb.co/hqSJFv

This is the method that gets called when the sign in is successful and request the messages from the database and displays them(this worked until i messed with decrypting) I want to read from DB and decrypt then display the messages

```
   //READ DECRYPT AND DISPLAY THE MESSAGES
      mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //called when new message is inserted into the list  also 
            //triggered for every child message

           EncryptoMessage encryptoMessage = 
           dataSnapshot.getValue(EncryptoMessage.class);
            //get the text from the encryptomessage object store as string
            String encryptedString = encryptoMessage.getText();  //value of 
            //encryptedString ends up empty 

            byte [] bytes = encryptedString.getBytes();
            String str = null;
            try {
                 str = new EncryptoMessage().decrypt(bytes);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            EncryptoMessage decryptedMessage = new EncryptoMessage();
            decryptedMessage.setText(str);
            mMessageAdapter.add(decryptedMessage);
        }
```

This is the message from user input encrypted and stored as a string in DB. I coverted the btye[] to a string

```
      //SEND CLICKED
    // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText && Write to the 
    //Database
         mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO: Send messages on click

            //get the message the user enters
          String messageText = mMessageEditText.getText().toString();

            byte[] codedtext = new byte[0];
            try {
                //take that message and encrypt it
                //codedtext now equal to byte array of messageText
                codedtext = new EncryptoMessage().encrypt(messageText);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //change the encrypted bytes into a string and send to the 
            //database
            String str = new String(codedtext, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            //Create an EncryptoMessage object for the message the user 
            //enters
            EncryptoMessage encryptoMessage = new EncryptoMessage(str, 
            mUsername, null);
            //add the new message object to the EncryptoChat database
            mMsgDatabaseReference.push().setValue(encryptoMessage);

            // Clear input box
            mMessageEditText.setText("");
        }
    });
```

This is Encrypted message object class(with encryption)

```
package com.google.firebase.david.encryptochat; //firebase API


import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

//**************************************
//THis class is our message object
//*****************************************
public class EncryptoMessage {

private String text;
private String name;
private String photoUrl;

public EncryptoMessage() {

    // Default constructor required for calls to 
    //DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
  }

// The encrypto message constructor to create the object
public EncryptoMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
    this.text = text;
    this.name = name;
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}
  //Copy constuctor

  /* public EncryptoMessage(EncryptoMessage EncryptoMessageCopy){
    this(EncryptoMessageCopy.getText(), EncryptoMessageCopy.getName());
}*/
public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return photoUrl;
}

public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}


   //Encryption of the messages

   public byte[] encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");

        final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9"
                .getBytes("utf-8"));

        final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }

        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
        final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);


        return cipherText;
       }
       //Decrypt

      public String decrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {

        //get the bytes if the string passing in
        //byte [] bytes = message.getBytes();

        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9"
                .getBytes("utf-8"));
        final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }

        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        final Cipher decipher = 
        Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

        return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
    }
```

}

This is the error i get at runtime just when i sign in and display messages it crashes also

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.google.firebase.david.encryptochat, PID: 8733
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference
      at com.google.firebase.david.encryptochat.MainActivity$4.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:238)
```

Comment: It doesn't end up empty. It's null. There's a difference. And how do you know that the default constructor is called? You don't have a Log statement there

Comment: in the encryptoMessage.java there is a constructor. This EncryptoMessage constructor is used by default by the firebase Snapshot function. Without it you cannot use snapshot. But when i request to getText() on the object the result is null like you said

Comment: Yes, you require the default constructor, I only asked why you think it's being called. Hint: it's the setter method that's actually the problem

Comment: Cheers for the reply dude. What setter method ? Could you give advise me where im gone wrong. I have been at this for hours :/

Comment: Can you please show your Firebase database using a screenshot, or the export JSON option?

Comment: `setText` method... Set a breakpoints in it and debug

Comment: Thanks for the help dude. I cant upload a json so Here's a link to a screenshot https://ibb.co/hqSJFv @cricket_007  Essentially all i want is the text from the DB decrypted and displayed

Comment: @cricket_007 What should i change in the setText method ?

Comment: Are you parameters wrong? What is `String photoUrl`?? Did you try any of the "getting started" examples on Firebase before adding this encryption stuff?

Comment: String photo URL is the photo that is send to storage but im not encrypting that. I used firebases friendly chat as a base and had everything up and running till i started decryption. I had it to the point where i was sending messages but on the phone they were encrypted and displayed encrypted. Now i just need to read from database decrypt and display.Thing is i cant seem to get the string thats stored.

Comment: This is how the message was stored : See screenshot https://ibb.co/jEop7a

Comment: Your image doesn't show a `photoUrl` was my point. I think you need to define a new constructor for `(String name, String text)`

Comment: @cricket_007 The messages with a photo are stored as a link like so https://ibb.co/fxP1Lv

Comment: The encryption works i tested it on its own with a main. Its simply getting the message itself from the DB calling the decrpyt() method and display that im struggling with

Comment: How about this: Can you `Log` the length of the name field? In other words, why are you so focused on the decryption, when the problem is likely elsewhere?

Comment: i dont get you sorry :P

Comment: Your error is the `getMessage()` method obviously, but you never attempted to use `getName()`. I bet you that it is also `null`. Please check it. If so, *the problem is not the encryption*

Comment: It was working 100% before i tried to decrypt

Comment: It worked as expected? Because without the encrypt/decrypt, then `mMessageAdapter.add(null);`, will "run", yes, but I don't think I would call that "working"

Comment: messageAdapter.add(encryptoMessage);  works 100% but the encryptoMessage passed in is the object with encrypted text. In my decrypt method then i try to create another message object and set the text but that doesnt work